# SPI не работает на beaglebone black с debian 9.4?

Tags: linux, debian, embedded, spi

На версии debian 7.8 все работало хорошо. Недавно пришло несколько новых BBB и я попытался загрузить свою копию ОС, но загрузка не происходит (с прошлыми BBB все нормально), вместо змейки светодиодов просто горит D4.
Решил перейти на последнюю версию, она нормально загружается, только проблема в том что SPI уже не работает, со всем остальным все нормально. Использую spi1.

Остался бы 7.8, но он не загружается(

bb.org-overlays обновлял

**Вот мой uEnv.txt:**

```
#Docs: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:U-boot_partitioning_layout_2.0

uname_r=4.14.49-ti-r54
#uuid=
#dtb=


###U-Boot Overlays###
###Documentation: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#U-Boot_Overlays
###Master Enable
enable_uboot_overlays=1
###
###Overide capes with eeprom
uboot_overlay_addr0=/lib/firmware/BB-CAN1-00A0.dtbo
uboot_overlay_addr1=/lib/firmware/BB-DGPIO1-00A0.dtbo
uboot_overlay_addr2=/lib/firmware/BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr3=/lib/firmware/<file3>.dtbo
###
###Additional custom capes
#uboot_overlay_addr4=/lib/firmware/<file4>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr5=/lib/firmware/<file5>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr6=/lib/firmware/<file6>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr7=/lib/firmware/<file7>.dtbo
###
###Custom Cape
#dtb_overlay=/lib/firmware/BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dtbo
###
###Disable auto loading of virtual capes (emmc/video/wireless/adc)
#disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
disable_uboot_overlay_video=1
disable_uboot_overlay_audio=1
disable_uboot_overlay_wireless=1
disable_uboot_overlay_adc=1
###
###PRUSS OPTIONS
###pru_rproc (4.4.x-ti kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-4-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_rproc (4.9.x-ti kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-9-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_rproc (4.14.x-ti kernel)
uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-14-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_uio (4.4.x-ti, 4.9.x-ti, 4.14.x-ti & mainline/bone kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-UIO-00A0.dtbo
###
###Cape Universal Enable
enable_uboot_cape_universal=1
###
###Debug: disable uboot autoload of Cape
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr0=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr1=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr2=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr3=1
###
###U-Boot fdt tweaks... (60000 = 384KB)
#uboot_fdt_buffer=0x60000
###U-Boot Overlays###

cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet

#In the event of edid real failures, uncomment this next line:
#cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e

##enable Generic eMMC Flasher:
##make sure, these tools are installed: dosfstools rsync
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh
```

**ls -al /dev/spidev*:**

```
crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 1 Aug  6 11:20 /dev/spidev2.0
crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 0 Aug  6 11:20 /dev/spidev2.1
```

**судя по "sudo /opt/scripts/tools/version.sh" конфликтов нет:**

```
git:/opt/scripts/:[31292bce1d4b35b497cc7a013d6d57e7e1f4f5c4]
eeprom:[A335BNLT00C01618BBBK1D78]
model:[TI_AM335x_BeagleBone_Black]
dogtag:[BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2018-06-17]
bootloader:[eMMC-(default)]:[/dev/mmcblk1]:[U-Boot 2018.03-00002-gac9cce7c6a]:[location: dd MBR]
kernel:[4.14.49-ti-r54]
nodejs:[v6.14.3]
uboot_overlay_options:[enable_uboot_overlays=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[uboot_overlay_addr0=/lib/firmware/BB-CAN1-00A0.dtbo]
uboot_overlay_options:[uboot_overlay_addr1=/lib/firmware/BB-DGPIO1-00A0.dtbo]
uboot_overlay_options:[uboot_overlay_addr2=/lib/firmware/BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dtbo]
uboot_overlay_options:[disable_uboot_overlay_video=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[disable_uboot_overlay_audio=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[disable_uboot_overlay_wireless=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[disable_uboot_overlay_adc=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-14-TI-00A0.dtbo]
uboot_overlay_options:[enable_uboot_cape_universal=1]
pkg check: to individually upgrade run: [sudo apt install --only-upgrade <pkg>]
pkg:[bb-cape-overlays]:[4.4.20180611.0-0rcnee0~stretch+20180611]
pkg:[bb-wl18xx-firmware]:[1.20180517-0rcnee0~stretch+20180517]
pkg:[kmod]:[23-2rcnee1~stretch+20171005]
pkg:[roboticscape]:[0.4.4-git20180608.0-0rcnee0~stretch+20180609]
pkg:[firmware-ti-connectivity]:[20170823-1rcnee1~stretch+20180328]
groups:[debian : debian adm kmem dialout cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev users systemd-journal i2c bluetooth netdev cloud9ide gpio pwm eqep admin spi tisdk weston-launch xenomai]
cmdline:[console=ttyO0,115200n8 bone_capemgr.uboot_capemgr_enabled=1 root=/dev/mmcblk1p1 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet]
dmesg | grep pinctrl-single
[    1.021129] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins at pa f9e10800 size 568
dmesg | grep gpio-of-helper
[    1.022280] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: ready
END
```

**dmesg ошибок вроде нет:**

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.14.49-ti-r54 (root@b2-am57xx-beagle-x15-2gb) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jun 15 22:14:13 UTC 2018
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT:
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 48 MiB at 0x9c800000
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 130560
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c15ed380, node_mem_map df961000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1148 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 130560 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.000000] AM335X ES2.1 (sgx neon)
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0xac/0x460 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 18 pages/cpu @df928000 s41548 r8192 d23988 u73728
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s41548 r8192 d23988 u73728 alloc=18*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129412
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyO0,115200n8 bone_capemgr.uboot_capemgr_enabled=1 root=/dev/mmcblk1p1 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 440488K/522240K available (13312K kernel code, 1168K rwdata, 4372K rodata, 1024K init, 673K bss, 32600K reserved, 49152K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
                   vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
                   fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
                   vmalloc : 0xe0000000 - 0xff800000   ( 504 MB)
                   lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xdfe00000   ( 510 MB)
                   pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
                   modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
                     .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0e00000   (14304 kB)
                     .init : 0xc1400000 - 0xc1500000   (1024 kB)
                     .data : 0xc1500000 - 0xc16241a8   (1169 kB)
                      .bss : 0xc162ec1c - 0xc16d709c   ( 674 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 42794 entries in 126 pages
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=2 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0xfa200000 (revision 5.0) with 128 interrupts
[    0.000000] OMAP clockevent source: timer2 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000018] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
[    0.000036] clocksource: timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.000047] OMAP clocksource: timer1 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000761] timer_probe: no matching timers found
[    0.000980] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001006] WARNING: Your 'console=ttyO0' has been replaced by 'ttyS0'
[    0.001010] This ensures that you still see kernel messages. Please
[    0.001014] update your kernel commandline.
[    0.001040] Calibrating delay loop... 995.32 BogoMIPS (lpj=1990656)
[    0.046919] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.047194] Security Framework initialized
[    0.047209] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.047250] AppArmor: AppArmor disabled by boot time parameter
[    0.047443] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.047457] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.048474] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.048985] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket -1, mpidr 0
[    0.063037] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100060
[    0.070939] Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.082064] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.086946] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.086961] smp: Brought up 1 node, 1 CPU
[    0.086972] SMP: Total of 1 processors activated (995.32 BogoMIPS).
[    0.086980] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.088557] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.103354] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3
[    0.103857] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.103882] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.107882] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    0.146986]    arm4regs  :  1217.000 MB/sec
[    0.186917]    8regs     :  1091.000 MB/sec
[    0.226916]    32regs    :  1088.000 MB/sec
[    0.266914]    neon      :  1675.000 MB/sec
[    0.266921] xor: using function: neon (1675.000 MB/sec)
[    0.266938] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.267725] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.268173] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.272088] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.299899] omap_hwmod: debugss: _wait_target_disable failed
[    0.340516] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.346549] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1
[    0.360218] No ATAGs?
[    0.360240] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.
[    0.360581] omap4_sram_init:Unable to allocate sram needed to handle errata I688
[    0.360592] omap4_sram_init:Unable to get sram pool needed to handle errata I688
[    0.454975] raid6: neonx2   gen()  1883 MB/s
[    0.522943] raid6: neonx2   xor()  1497 MB/s
[    0.522952] raid6: using algorithm neonx2 gen() 1883 MB/s
[    0.522958] raid6: .... xor() 1497 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    0.522965] raid6: using neon recovery algorithm
[    0.530266] edma 49000000.edma: TI EDMA DMA engine driver
[    0.533515] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.535115] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.535411] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.535473] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.535593] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.536163] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /ocp/l4_wkup@44c00000/scm@210000/pinmux@800/pinmux_i2c0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.537616] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: bus 2 rev0.11 at 100 kHz
[    0.537889] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.537940] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.538105] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.538113] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.538133] PTP clock support registered
[    0.538256] dmi: Firmware registration failed.
[    0.538708] omap-mailbox 480c8000.mailbox: omap mailbox rev 0x400
[    0.543270] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.543972] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.543983] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.543989] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    0.544075] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.547441] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer1
[    0.713973] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.714091] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.726069] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.726953] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.727000] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.727058] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.727169] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.727192] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.727411] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.736428] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.736437] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.736443] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.736448] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.737070] Unpacking initramfs...
[    1.014490] Freeing initrd memory: 4360K
[    1.015125] hw perfevents: no interrupt-affinity property for /pmu, guessing.
[    1.015393] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a8 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    1.017263] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    1.018467] audit: type=2000 audit(1.016:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    1.018600] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    1.019512] random: fast init done
[    1.024702] zbud: loaded
[    1.032024] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.032077] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.032083] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.032102] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.032461] fuse init (API version 7.26)
[    1.033362] orangefs_debugfs_init: called with debug mask: :none: :0:
[    1.033571] orangefs_init: module version upstream loaded
[    1.033580] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[    1.044491] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.044507] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.044647] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 243)
[    1.048988] io scheduler noop registered
[    1.048999] io scheduler deadline registered
[    1.049384] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    1.049395] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.050974] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins at pa f9e10800 size 568
[    1.052539] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: ready
[    1.054773] wkup_m3_ipc 44e11324.wkup_m3_ipc: could not get rproc handle
[    1.056309] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 6 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    1.059929] 44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 30, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    1.076271] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.078768] omap_rng 48310000.rng: Random Number Generator ver. 20
[    1.079969] [drm] Initialized vgem 1.0.0 20120112 for virtual device on minor 0
[    1.080074] usbcore: registered new interface driver udl
[    1.084180] at24 2-0054: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    1.084474] at24 2-0055: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    1.084706] at24 2-0056: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    1.084924] at24 2-0057: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    1.089821] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.090664] CAN device driver interface
[    1.092033] c_can_platform 481d0000.can: c_can_platform device registered (regs=fa1d0000, irq=36)
[    1.143478] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: davinci mdio revision 1.6, bus freq 1000000
[    1.143494] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: detected phy mask fffffffe
[    1.143915] davinci_mdio: dt: updated phy_id[0] from phy_mask[fffffffe]
[    1.157843] libphy: 4a101000.mdio: probed
[    1.157872] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: phy[0]: device 4a101000.mdio:00, driver SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720
[    1.158900] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: Detected MACID = 74:e1:82:86:c7:8c
[    1.159010] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: initialized cpsw ale version 1.4
[    1.159020] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: ALE Table size 1024
[    1.159058] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: cpts: overflow check period 1250 (jiffies)
[    1.161823] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.161882] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.162072] ehci-omap: OMAP-EHCI Host Controller driver
[    1.162573] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.165326] am335x-phy-driver 47401300.usb-phy: 47401300.usb-phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.168221] am335x-phy-driver 47401b00.usb-phy: 47401b00.usb-phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.182514] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: already running
[    1.183279] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: registered as rtc0
[    1.184580] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.187237] omap_wdt: OMAP Watchdog Timer Rev 0x01: initial timeout 60 sec
[    1.187781] softdog: initialized. soft_noboot=0 soft_margin=60 sec soft_panic=0 (nowayout=1)
[    1.188885] cpuidle: enable-method property 'ti,am3352' found operations
[    1.189370] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.189376] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.189811] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: Got CD GPIO
[    1.267847] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.269301] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.269702] omap-aes 53500000.aes: OMAP AES hw accel rev: 3.2
[    1.270166] omap-aes 53500000.aes: will run requests pump with realtime priority
[    1.275953] omap-sham 53100000.sham: hw accel on OMAP rev 4.3
[    1.279337] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.280494] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.280505] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.283629] remoteproc remoteproc0: wkup_m3 is available
[    1.287915] wireguard: WireGuard 0.0.20180531 loaded. See www.wireguard.com for information.
[    1.287927] wireguard: Copyright (C) 2015-2018 Jason A. Donenfeld <Jason@zx2c4.com>. All Rights Reserved.
[    1.288773] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.294504] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    1.294590] mip6: Mobile IPv6
[    1.294607] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.294624] can: controller area network core (rev 20170425 abi 9)
[    1.294724] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[    1.294840] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.294847] mpls_gso: MPLS GSO support
[    1.294858] NET: Registered protocol family 44
[    1.295204] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added
[    1.302186] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    1.302213] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.303214] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.303359] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    1.306420] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic
[    1.306523] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass! (rc=-19)
[    1.306550] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha256
[    1.322100] mmc1: new high speed MMC card at address 0001
[    1.322997] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 M62704 3.56 GiB
[    1.323527] mmcblk1boot0: mmc1:0001 M62704 partition 1 2.00 MiB
[    1.323934] mmcblk1boot1: mmc1:0001 M62704 partition 2 2.00 MiB
[    1.324314] mmcblk1rpmb: mmc1:0001 M62704 partition 3 512 KiB
[    1.325856]  mmcblk1: p1
[    1.353081] input: tps65217_pwr_but as /devices/platform/ocp/44e0b000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0024/tps65217-pwrbutton/input/input0
[    1.353683] tps65217 0-0024: TPS65217 ID 0xe version 1.2
[    1.354169] at24 0-0050: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    1.354281] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
[    1.356086] remoteproc remoteproc0: powering up wkup_m3
[    1.356202] remoteproc remoteproc0: Booting fw image am335x-pm-firmware.elf, size 217168
[    1.359754] remoteproc remoteproc0: remote processor wkup_m3 is now up
[    1.359774] wkup_m3_ipc 44e11324.wkup_m3_ipc: CM3 Firmware Version = 0x193
[    1.366567] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1: MUSB HDRC host driver
[    1.366606] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.366932] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.366943] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.366952] usb usb1: Product: MUSB HDRC host driver
[    1.366960] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.14.49-ti-r54 musb-hcd
[    1.366967] usb usb1: SerialNumber: musb-hdrc.1
[    1.367921] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.367990] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.371739] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: setting system clock to 2018-08-07 11:00:30 UTC (1533639630)
[    1.371759] of_cfs_init
[    1.371932] of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.372580] ALSA device list:
[    1.372588]   No soundcards found.
[    1.377337] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[    1.527351] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.528547] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.528662] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    4.241276] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.705238] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    4.742437] systemd[1]: systemd 232 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
[    4.743188] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    4.744549] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <beaglebone>.
[    5.372979] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    5.374044] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    5.374424] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    5.374803] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.375835] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    5.376096] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    5.376571] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    5.611651] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    6.757147] systemd-journald[257]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   11.456639] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (8192 buckets, 32768 max)
[   12.900236] net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)
[   12.972921] SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720 4a101000.mdio:00: attached PHY driver [SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720] (mii_bus:phy_addr=4a101000.mdio:00, irq=POLL)
[   13.002152] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   13.642293] using random self ethernet address
[   13.642314] using random host ethernet address
[   13.819827] using random self ethernet address
[   13.819848] using random host ethernet address
[   14.313295] Mass Storage Function, version: 2009/09/11
[   14.313323] LUN: removable file: (no medium)
[   14.532683] usb0: HOST MAC 74:e1:82:86:c7:8d
[   14.536510] usb0: MAC 74:e1:82:86:c7:8e
[   14.551963] usb1: HOST MAC 74:e1:82:86:c7:90
[   14.554683] usb1: MAC 74:e1:82:86:c7:91
[   14.816968] configfs-gadget gadget: high-speed config #1: c
[   15.297152] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): usb0: link is not ready
[   15.503720] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): usb1: link is not ready
[   15.572219] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): usb0: link becomes ready
[   16.032992] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   16.033081] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   16.284080] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   16.284183] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0
[   24.227854] random: crng init done
[   24.227879] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   26.656410] pruss 4a300000.pruss: creating PRU cores and other child platform devices
[   26.733708] remoteproc remoteproc1: 4a334000.pru is available
[   26.733838] pru-rproc 4a334000.pru: PRU rproc node /ocp/pruss_soc_bus@4a326004/pruss@0/pru@34000 probed successfully
[   26.860131] remoteproc remoteproc2: 4a338000.pru is available
[   26.860259] pru-rproc 4a338000.pru: PRU rproc node /ocp/pruss_soc_bus@4a326004/pruss@0/pru@38000 probed successfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем версия eMMC изменилась с 5 на 5.1 и в старых версия не поддерживается.
Как я понимаю изменились адреса разделов.
Нужно [обновить ядро](https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Kernel_Upgrade) Debian 7.9

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo cd /opt/scripts/tools/
sudo git pull
sudo ./update_kernel.sh
sudo reboot
```

Теперь устанавливается без проблем. С spi на 9.4 так и не понял в чем проблема

Comment: Pin muxing скорее всего не такой.